# mongodb query to find mutual likes to output count and profiles

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections:

**users** - profiles of all users

**partnership** - users liked each other.

How to find for a given user (use "rrr" as the user for this example)

- number of mutual likes
- profiles of mutual likers

The expected output is count of 2 AND profiles of users "abc" and "eee" because both these users have mutually liked "rrr".

Here is the db

```
db={
  users: [
    {
      _id: "abc",
      name: "abc",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "xyz",
      name: "xyyy",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "123",
      name: "yyy",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr",
      name: "tttt",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "eee",
      name: "uuu",
      group: 1
    }
  ],
  partnership: [
    {
      _id: "abc_123",
      fromUser: "abc",
      toUser: "123"
    },
    {
      _id: "eee_rrr",
      fromUser: "eee",
      toUser: "rrr"
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr_abc",
      fromUser: "rrr",
      toUser: "abc"
    },
    {
      _id: "abc_rrr",
      fromUser: "abc",
      toUser: "rrr"
    },
    {
      _id: "xyz_rrr",
      fromUser: "xyz",
      toUser: "rrr"
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr_eee",
      fromUser: "rrr",
      toUser: "eee"
    },
    
  ]
}
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/jnW6fPOTd8I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to start from the `partnership` collections:

1. Keep only documents that contains `rrr`
2. `$group` to find all its partners
3. Find the set intersection between its `from`s and `to`s, these are the mutual partners.
4. `$lookup` to bring the `user`s data
5. Add `count`

```
db.partnership.aggregate([
  {$match: {$or: [{fromUser: "rrr"}, {toUser: "rrr"}]}},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      from: {$addToSet: "$fromUser"},
      to: {$addToSet: "$toUser"}
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      users: {
        $filter: {
          input: {$setIntersection: ["$from", "$to"]},
          cond: {$ne: ["$$this", "rrr"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "users",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {$project: {users: 1, count: {$size: "$users"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cXhAyK3bgCb)